# Chrome: Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascipt and just trying out some examples I found in the net. This one doesn't work at all. I open about:blank in Chrome and use a Console there. When I run this code there's an error `Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined'`.

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true}, getAllOpenWindows);

    function getAllOpenWindows(winData) {

      var tabs = [];
      for (var i in winData) {
        if (winData[i].focused === true) {
            var winTabs = winData[i].tabs;
            var totTabs = winTabs.length;
            for (var j=0; j<totTabs;j++) {
              tabs.push(winTabs[j].url);
            }
        }
      }
      console.log(tabs);
    }
```

Also it seems like `chrome` doesn't have property `windows` in it...

Comment: I'm surprised that it has `chrome` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems like it is using the Chrome Extensions API. You can't just run it in the console. You can get started with Chrome extension development [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out... I really hoped the example could be run in the console..

Comment: @parsecer Great. Please mark this as the answer is it answered your question.